# AngularJS form validation while adding dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, angularjs

I have a form with AngularJS validation.
The problem is that I add input elements to this form using Jquery and AngularJS doesn't add those elements into the form's validation..
Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ULEsy/

```
var input = $compile($('<input type="text" ng-model="textinput" required />'))($scope);
$("#someform").append(input);
```

In the example, even though the input field is not valid (empty - can be seen by the red border), the entire form is valid.
Any help?

Comment: I don't have much experience with angular, but [this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1404) might be a start.

Comment: I already saw this thread.. The difference is that there Angular is the one that is adding the elements to the form.. And in my case it is jquery..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@Ephi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102783/ephi-gabay) and I found a solution for this problem.
Apparently, you need to first append the element to the DOM, and only then use $compile. Also, the new element needs a name.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5MJLP/2/)

```
angular.module("app", []).controller('someController', function($scope, $compile) {   
    $scope.add = function() {
        var input = $('<input type="text" ng-model="textinput" name="x" required />');
        $("#someform4").append(input);    
        $compile(input)($scope);
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI if you want to remove an element you should remove it and then compile its parent..